# Why yellow arrow go back in nemiver when it shouldn't?

Tags: debugging, gdb, gnome

I use Nemiver 0.9.2 and i don't understand why the "current line executed" (marked by the yellow arrow) often go back when i hit <kbd>F6</kbd> (Next).

Here is an example when using nemiver on sshd:

1) I start nemiver with:
`nemiver $(pwd)/build-deb/sshd -p 1234 -d`

2) Nemiver starts and reaches the breakpoint on main():
[image: yellow arrow at line 1322]

3) I hit <kbd>F6</kbd>, nemiver skips all the variable declarations and stop on the first instruction:
[image: yellow arrow at line 1340]

4) I hit <kbd>F6</kbd> a second time, and i'm back on main() !!
[image: yellow arrow back at line 1322]

Do you have any idea why nemiver behaves like this ? Is it "normal" or is it a bug ? It is very disturbing when debugging

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you should look for is optimization. If the compiled code is optimized then the source code does not always match up and you end up with a jumping line marker.